# Integral is resulted by algebraic manipulation

Tags: calculus, integration

How this integral turned to be like this? This is not common integration by parts, seems.

$$\int{x\sqrt{4x-1}}\,dx=\int{\frac{1}{4}(4x-1)\sqrt{4x-1}}\,dx+\frac{1}{4}\int{\sqrt{4x-1}}\,dx$$

The result would be
$$\frac{1}{10}(4x-1)^{2}\sqrt{4x-1}+\frac{1}{6}(4x-1)\sqrt{4x-1}+\text{const.}$$

Comment: $$x=\dfrac{4x-1}4+\dfrac14$$